# htaccess rewrite condition old site to new site with querystring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritecond

I am not even going to pretend to fully understand how htaccess rewrite conditions work. I've been working on this for a while searching and searching.

I have an old Wordpress site `www.old-site.com` and a new site `www.site.com`.  Wordpress uses query strings `page_id=#` to redirect to pages.

On the old site `page_id=2` went to a specific page but on the new site it goes the the home page.

I need `old-site/?page_id=2` to go to `site.com/our-company`

Here is what I am trying

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^page_id=2$ 
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/our-company/ [R=301,L]
```

If I take out the rewrite condition for query string it redirects all traffic from old-site.com to the company page on the new site.  Where am I going wrong?

I have about 15 redirects I need to do this way.

Comment: Have you enabled rewritelog? If not, start by doing that. Usually the problem is due to something you are trying to match not being what you expect it to be. The rewritelog will tell you exactly what is being matched against what.

Comment: Your problem is btw, a good candidate for a rewrite map: http://serverfault.com/a/496796/163704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fyi answered my own question

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^page_id=2$ 
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/our-company/? [R=301,L]
```

without the `?` after the new url it apends the query string to the end of it adding `?` ends the line there

ill look into this rewrite map
thanks